# Select and insert on the same table

Tags: sql

Can you tell me what is wrong with this query:

```
INSERT INTO properties 
(
    f_gen_id(NULL)
    , 'ASHAgroup18E'
    , entity
    , effective_dt
    , property_key
    , property_value
    , created_by
    , create_ts
    , updated_by
    , update_ts
) 
SELECT f_gen_id(NULL)
, 'ASHAgroup18E'
, entity
, effective_dt
, property_key
, property_value
, description
, created_by
, create_ts
, updated_by
, update_ts
 -- 'UIL-Migration', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'UIL-Migration', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
FROM properties 
WHERE group_key = 'ASHAgroup18B';
```

Comment: What makes you think there's something wrong with the query?

Comment: `INSERT INTO tablename (column1, column2, ...) SELECT ...`, i.e. spccify insert columns.

Comment: Also, what is `f_gen_id(NULL)`?

Comment: f_gen_id(NULL)?- this is idgen value we are marking as null

Comment: above query is giving me error 'sql syntax exception'

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: Why would you keep the old timestamps on the new rows?

Answer (score 3):

In the INSERT part you should have column names, not a function

```
INSERT INTO properties (f_gen_id(NULL),...
```

replace this with the name of the primary key/id column

```
INSERT INTO properties (id,...
```

*Update*
 I guess also the second column in the INSERT is incorrect since it contains a string. Again, replace it with a column name